# How to reliably detect whether BULK API is enabled for an org

Tags: api, bulk-api, bulk

We have a managed package which loads data into customer Salesforce orgs. We attempt to use the BULK API first and fall back to the REST API if necessary. So we need to be able to detect if the BULK API is enabled.

In our test orgs, if the BULK API is disabled (e.g. Professional Edition), when we try to submit a job, we get FeatureNotEnabled exceptions. This also worked for all our customer orgs pre Spring 2014.

However since Spring 2014, for customer orgs where BULK API is disabled, we are actually able to submit a BULK job. It is only when we go to retrieve the job results, we get Batch errors saying "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG".

Is there any way to check if the BULK API is enabled, without submitting a job and polling the results? Does anyone know why we are not seeing a FeatureNotEnabled exception on our customer orgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way as it is an Org wide permission but you can always ask your customers to have this feature enabled and also you can check on the profile of the user as he needs to have the “API Enabled” permission to use BULK API.